# get alert when instance is not active in GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

For Compute Engine of GCE, I use stackdriver monitoring for monitoring and alert.
For most of the general metrics like CPU, disk IO, memory ... etc is available and can set alert for those metrics based or dead-or-alive by process name.

However I cannot find any metrics related to status of GCE instance itself.

My use-case is so simply. I'd like to know if the instance id down or not.
Any suggestion appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

think the instance status not a [monitoring metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp); there's just `instance/uptime` available.

(and I have no clue what it would return when it is `terminated`, possibly worth a try).

but one can check for servers with [Uptime Checks](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/) and then report the [Incident](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/incidents-events).

and one can get the [instance status](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/checking-instance-status) with `gcloud compute instances describe instance01`.

Answer (score 0):

You could monitor the parameter absence (like CPU), it is the only official way:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/metric-absence

- [GCP Send Alert While VM is Down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76392282/gcp-send-alert-while-vm-is-down)
- [GCP alert if the instance is stopped or down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69435889/gcp-alert-if-the-instance-is-stopped-or-down?noredirect=1&lq=1)