# GCP alert if the instance is stopped or down

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I want to setup an alert if my vm is stopped or down it should send me alerts , as i had previously configured by selecting
1.metric type :- cpu usage
2.condition :- is absent

but did not get any mail

so how can we achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have received an alert as per metric absent configuration made under alerting.
Below are some steps and field selection which might help you with your requirements.

Select your resource type which is virtual machine here in case and
Choose metric as CPU utilization

Aggregator - select as “mean”

Go to “show advanced options” under alerting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG4Kh.png)

Advanced aggregation

Step 1 :
Aligner - change the field to “count“ (this will be more suited choice if the target is to check if instance is up or down - we’ll be just figure if matrix have any data or not)

Alignment period - you could try for 1 min.

#Step 2 : Select the condition as “is absent” and suitable time duration as per your choice to get notified of the instance state.

Comment: I hope if this was of help to you. If it answered your question, click the check mark to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped