# GCP Send Alert While VM is Down

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, alert

I am looking for a way to get GCP to send an alert if a VM is stopped or down.

I found this post, [GCP alert if the instance is stopped or down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69435889/gcp-alert-if-the-instance-is-stopped-or-down/69438030#69438030), and followed the steps (create monitor policy based on missing CPU usage metric). They worked fine, except that I only got an alert that my VM was stopped after I restarted it. While the VM was down nothing came from GCP. Is there something else that needs to be done to get GCP to alert me that a VM is down while the VM is down and not after the fact?

Thanks,
Ed.

Comment: You have not provided details on the alert policy or alert channel that you configured. Use commands such as `gcloud alpha monitoring policies describe` and `gcloud alpha monitoring channels describe` to get details on the policy and alert channel.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the reference [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69435889/gcp-alert-if-the-instance-is-stopped-or-down/69438030#69438030) and it mentioned something about metric absence. As per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/metric-absence), "metrics associated with TERMINATED or DELETED Google Cloud resources are not considered for metric-absence policies". Thus, you can't use this metric absence policies to test for stopped instances.

Although, what I can suggest for the workaround is that:

You can create a [log-based metric alerting policy](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/log-based-alerts) which alerts you based on a specific message found in the logs. (eg. If you configured it to send you an email if your VM stopped/is down, then you will be alerted on that).

To create the log based alerts:

1. Go to Log Explorer > Create alert
2. Provide the "Alert details" and under "Choose logs to include in the alert", you can enter this in the log filter but you can also modify this according to your use-case.

"resource.type="gce_instance"
protoPayload.methodName=(v1.compute.instances.stop OR beta.compute.instances.stop OR v1.compute.instances.hostError OR beta.compute.instances.hostError OR v1.compute.instances.guestTerminate OR beta.compute.instances.guestTerminate OR beta.compute.instances.terminateOnHostMaintenance OR v.compute.instances.terminateOnHostMaintenance)”

1. Configure the "Set notification frequency and autoclose duration" and "Who should be notified". > Click Save.

I hope the above information helps.